# loading tensorflow models in java

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-storage, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml, tensorflow-datasets

```
exportDir = "gs://testbucket/export/";
SavedModelBundle b = SavedModelBundle.load(exportDir, "serve");
```

Gives me the error :

> org.tensorflow.TensorFlowException: SavedModel not found in export directory: gs://testbucket/export/

copying the saved_model.pb to a local directory and then providing path to the local filesystem works.

Where as

```
tf.saved_model.loader.load(session, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], export_dir)
```

This works with gcs bucket. Does any one know if loading models using svedmodelBundle api does not support gcs bucket ? How can i load saved_model.pb and variables from gcs bucket without copying them over to local filesystem in java

Comment: I suspect the GCS module is not compiled in by default. Let me verify and get back to you.

Comment: doesn't the python saved_model loader and savedBundle api in java call the same underneath C library ? Can we please fix this as i need to be able to access large model files with checkpoints and variables from gcs on distributed workers

Comment: In Java, libtensorflow_jni is used, which is precompiled. While the source code is definitely the same as Python, the Python build does not use libtensorflow_jni and possibly comes with a different set of options. I'm still verifying how libtensorflow_jni is built. We will also consider ways to offer a binary with GCS support.

Comment: Also, have you considered using tf-serving which will handle serving out of the box (e.g. your Java servers can issue an RPC to tf-serving)? And if you want an easy way to deploy tf-serving (for free), you can try Kubeflow on any Kubernetes cluster. CloudML Engine is a paid option that will soon support large memory machines.

Comment: i want to serve the models in hundreds or thousands of servers already running on gce . Also tf-serving wont be able to handle qps and latency requirements from my previous discussion. Also i want to be able to evaluate models on apache beam , basically running inference on billions of records (10+ Tb of data), so ideally we would like to be able to load models from gcs

Comment: We're happy to help you get going with what you need, so don't interpret what I'm saying as telling you how to do things, just things to consider.

tf-serving is an open-source, highly efficient model serving library/binary so it can easily handle your qps / latency (probably better than Java). The challenge I foresee is deploying it, which Kubeflow helps simplify (but it seems you aren't using Kubernetes).

Comment: I'll keep working on seeing what to do about the JNI build, but we'd also be interested in chatting with you directly. If you're willing can you email cloudml-feedback@ (this isn't about cloudml, that's the easiest group to email)?

Comment: Would there be an easy way to possibly do it on offline pipeline , apache beam first , i would like to read some models and run some inference. How can i have the beam/dataflow workers load the model . I will definitely want to look at using tf-serving as a library (rather than a separate binary for rpc call) solution as well to begin with.

Comment: Do you have some code pointers on how i can use tf-serving as  a library in my already existing servers ?

Comment: There are a couple of options available for batch inference in Beam, but mostly available in Python. I think most of the value of tf-serving is in the binary form; just using it as a library probably may not add value beyond what you are already trying.

We'd love to better understand your use case if you're willing to chat over phone/VC.

Comment: sure how can i schedule a hangout, i already have a ticket open on google enterprise

Comment: send your contact info to cloudml-feedback@ and we'll schedule something. Provide the details of your open support case.

Comment: I'm submitting a change right now to include GCP by default. I expect it to hit github in 1-2 days. If this is urgent, you can build the library yourself. I will work to get this officially into the official TF 1.8 release, though the schedule is tight.

Comment: On further investigation it appears to me that libtensorflow_jni does include GCP in version 1.6 onwards, but didn't include it in 1.4. Is your Java program using TensorFlow 1.4? Could you try with 1.6 or 1.7?

Comment: i tried 1.7, it didn't work

Comment: With the same error or something different? (I ask because I seem to be able to use the release binaries of 1.7 and load off of GCS)

Comment: let me try again , my intellij is probably still inking to 1.4 and giving this error , let me reconfirm

Comment: ok confirmed , this is not working in 1.4, 1.6, 1.7

Comment: 2018-04-20 14:16:48.543996: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:291] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: fail. Took 53 microseconds.
Exception in thread "main" org.tensorflow.TensorFlowException: SavedModel not found in export directory: gs://

Comment: Hmm...for the record, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/asimshankar/3dc41fc75733a341319f23b6a07264df) demonstrates what worked for me.

Comment: weird i verified locally i am using correct version but still doesnt work on gcs , trying to create a new gcs bucket :018-04-20 16:10:53.708471: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:196] Running LegacyInitOp on SavedModel bundle.
2018-04-20 16:10:54.324983: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:291] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success. Took 2196565 microseconds.
TensorFlow version: 1.7.0, Model MetaGraphLength: 18154079

Comment: is it possible tensorflow java version is using some other jni version underneeath ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169473/discussion-between-ash-and-user179156).

Comment: @rhaertel80, did you come up with a solution after the proposed hangout? If that was the case, would you mind posting it here as an answer? Thank you.

Comment: @ash was a solution discovered? rodrigo: ash took over, and should have more details. It seems that TF >= 1.6 on linux should have it, but possibly on mac it does not.

Comment: Yeah, it seems the Linux builds do have GCS linked in, the Mac and Windows ones do not. For Mac you'll have to build from source till the next release. Hope that helps

Comment: @ash, if possible, could you please post an answer with the main points that were discussed in the chat and what solution was found there? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING is the string 'serving_default'

Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: also if tag mismatch the error message is different saying could not find any graph with that particular tag ,